# Prerender IO working on localhost test but not with prod side

Tags: prerender

I Have an app the frontend is built using VUEjs the backend is served through Django on a Heroku app. When testing locally the prerender works fine (download the git hub repo, start the local server on 3000 and check the site), howevwe when using

```js
curl -A Googlebot <customsite url>
```

it does not render the html, when watching the logs on prerender.io I can see the requests coming through.

On the django side I have used the django-seo-js plugin, is there something I am still missing?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was not detailed enough with examples but I did find a solution to my problem from the prerender.io knowledge base

> In May of 2018, Google introduced "Dynamic Rendering" for serving normal JavaScript to your users and serving Prerendered pages to search engines. This is exactly what we do at Prerender.io.

> The change introduced by Google for Dynamic Rendering means they will stop crawling the ?*escaped_fragment*= URLs and you can now serve a prerendered page to Googlebot by checking their user agent directly. That might sound like cloaking, but Google introduced a policy change where they are allowing you to send prerendered pages to Googlebot by checking their user agent.

> Due to this Dynamic Rendering announcement, we have changed our middleware to add Googlebot to the list of user agents being checked directly.

That being said when looking at the useragent.py file

```
 # These first three should be disabled, since they support escaped 
  fragments, and
# and leaving them enabled will penalize a website as "cloaked".
# "Googlebot",
# "Yahoo",
# "bingbot",
```

Googlebot is still commented out in django-seo-js, to fix this I had to add it to the list manually in settings.py

```
 SEO_JS_USER_AGENTS=(
"Googlebot",
# "Yahoo",
# "bingbot",

"Ask Jeeves",
"baiduspider",
"facebookexternalhit",
"twitterbot",
"rogerbot",
"linkedinbot",
"embedly",
"quoralink preview'",
"showyoubot",
"outbrain",
"pinterest",
"developersgoogle.com/+/web/snippet",
)
```

Since the variable value is not appended to an existing list we have to add them all.

Comment: Apparently there is a PR in for this fix which hasnt been merged yet 


https://github.com/skoczen/django-seo-js/pull/37